# logstash mutate filter always stringifies hash and array

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a json log file, which I am taking as a input with this config

```
input {
   file { filename }
   codec { json_lines }
}
```

Each line is a deeply nested JSON.

In the filters,

When I say

```
mutate { add_field => { "new_field_name" => "%{old_field_name}"}
```

- if the old_field is a nested hash/array it is converted to a string and then added. Is there anyway I can preserve the type instead of stringifying it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using the ruby filter to duplicate the array:

```
filter  {
    ruby { code => "event['newhash'] = event['myhash']" }
}
```

I don't think there is a cleaner solution.

Apart from that, do you really use the json_lines codec with the file input? From logstash doc:

> Do not use this codec if your source input is line-oriented JSON, for
>   example, redis or file inputs. Rather, use the json codec.

Comment: json_lines is a mistake. json is the actual code we use.